# jQuery add 2 IDs to equal content

Tags: jquery, html, image, click

Here is what I have so far. http://jsfiddle.net/Scybf/22/

```
$('[id^=content]').hide();
$('#baseSection, #headSection').on("click", "li", function () {
    var id = ($(this).parent().attr('id') == 'selectable') ? $(this).attr('id').replace('base', '') : $(this).attr('id').replace('head', '');
    $("#customContent").html($("#content-" + id).html());
});
```

What I need it to do is take the ID's of base and head to equal content. example, base1 + head1 = content1 or base1 + head 2 = content2.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: base1 + head2 = content2? and not  base2 + head2 = content2.

Comment: sorry it is hard to understand what you are trying to do, can you show us some input/output?

Comment: The idea is a custom tool concept so the user will click one a base part in section 1 then click a head part in section 2, then it would display the combined result which would be an image and content.

Comment: Then edit your HTML to *show* what's going on, as it is this question doesn't make any sense. Possibly this is because your intent isn't reflected in the mark-up. Ideally add clear comments on what you'd like us to click on, and what the result of clicking on those element(s) would be. Also: add your ([minimal/representative](http://sscce.org/)) HTML to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help you:

You need to defined if the user clicked on a `head` or `base` element:

```
function isBase(element){
    return element.parents('div').attr('id').indexOf('base') !== -1;
} 

function isHead(element){
    return element.parents('div').attr('id').indexOf('head') !== -1;
}
```

Then you can create a buffer object:

```
var buffer = {head: null, base: null};
```

Then you just need to save the user action and display it in your `baseContent` element

```
$('#baseSection, #headSection').on("click", "li", function () {
    if (isHead($(this))) {
        buffer.head = $(this).text();
    } else if (isBase($(this))) {
        buffer.base = $(this).text();
    }

    $("#baseContent").html(
        "Head: " + buffer.head + "<br/>Base:" + buffer.base);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a common class to each list you can do something like this:

```
$('.selectable').on("click", "li", function () {
        var $li=$(this).addClass('selected')
        $li.siblings().removeClass('selected');
        var contentNum= this.id.replace( /\D/g,'')
        var $container= $li.closest('#headSection').length ? $('#headContent') : $('#baseContent');
        $container.html( $('#content-'+contentNum).html())

    });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Scybf/20/